# C++ code to open a file in vim for editing in a terminal window from Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, vim, terminal, openframeworks

i've been doing a search and can't quite seem to find a solution for this.

I am coding a realtime openGL visual application using openFrameworks in Xcode.

What I would like to do is to let the user press a button which opens up a terminal window with a glsl script ready for editing in vim.

So, I need to find some c++ code that

1. lets me launch a new terminal window
2. send commands to it in order to load a file in vim
3. close the terminal window

If anyone could point me in the right direction either with code examples or c++ libraries to look into that would be amazing. Thanks.

Comment: What about system call http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/system.html ?

Comment: That sounds like a job for AppleScript.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to open a process (like vim) with a system call, but a little trickier to open Terminal and then vim inside of that.  As an alternative, I'd recommend installing Macvim (https://code.google.com/p/macvim/) which you can easily launch and control with an `ofSystem` call or, if you need finer-grained control, `Poco::Process` (http://pocoproject.org/slides/150-Processes.pdf).  Since openFrameworks is built with Poco in the core, `Poco::Process` makes launching things easy.

Finally, as an alternative to all of that, you might look at the newly updated ofxGLEditor (https://github.com/Akira-Hayasaka/ofxGLEditor) that was just overhauled to allow live coding.  You might be able to use it to edit directly in your app.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the response man. I am currently using ofxGLEditor but its not very nice to use in practice compared to vim. going to take a look at URXVT/BSPWM as another idea as seen in this oF app -> http://nnkd.org/dexui/